# How to pass data back with no storyboard using Swift

Tags: swift

I have 2 controllers. Let's call them A and B

Controller A is the main one and I have to check in `viewWillAppear()` if `user` exists.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let user = currentUser else {
            let setupProfileViewController = SetupProfileViewController()
            print("Current user empty")
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: setupProfileViewController)
            present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
    }
```

Here user sees controller B and needs to fill data. On submit I validate all fields and create new `User`. Then I am dismissing B controller.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    let matchViewController = MatchViewController()
    matchViewController.currentUser = user
    matchViewController.kolodaView.reloadData()
}
```

But what happens it A controller says there is no value in `currentUser`. I appreciate any advice on how to solve this.

Comment: Where are you initializing currentUser?

Comment: In controller B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
let matchViewController = MatchViewController()
matchViewController.currentUser = user
```

is a new instance of the class not the currently presented one , so setting user to it has no value , you have to use delegate or share your user via singleton class

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Didn't realize that.

Comment: Don’t use singleton for passing data.

Comment: I meant for having a shared user across the whole app